# Reassigning a variable's value

Tags: python, string

This is a question from a complete noob. I have the following code:

```
nb='([- ][0-9]*.[0-9]*E[-+ ][0-9]*)'
nb='([0-9,E.+-]+)'
```

Is `nb` overwritten? Or does it do something else?

Comment: Your second assignment `nb='([0-9,E.+-]+)'` overwrites your original assignment `nb='([- ][0-9]*.[0-9]*E[-+ ][0-9]*)'`.

Comment: Thx, I found this statements in some application's code, and I coudn't understand what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nb` is now bound to the second string, `'([0-9,E.+-]+)'`. So your first assignment no longer matters. Remember that `nb` is simply a name which now points to the second string after previously pointing to the first one, you are not modifying any strings.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, the second assignment replaces the reference to the first string object with a reference to the second string object.

Since the first string object has no more references to it it will be garbage-collected (memory reclaimed) at that time or perhaps some time later.

Answer (score 1):

The first assignment will create an instance of type str in memory containing '([- ][0-9]*.[0-9]*E[-+ ][0-9]*)'.

In Python strings are immutable, so the second assignment will not modify the first string: it will create a second string instance in memory containing '([0-9,E.+-]+)'.

At some point the garbage collector will wipe the first instance from memory because the reference count is now zero (there is no variable referring to that string anymore, since nb points to another string now).